# How to transform object from Cycles Render to Blender Render

Tags: blender

I have blender file which loads the scene fine in Cycles Render.
However, I need it to correctly load the textures in Blender Render.
Any hints how I can achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For simple materials it can be easier to re-create the same look using blender internal material settings. For more complex materials the best you can do is [bake the cycles material](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/baking.html) to an image that you can then use in blender internal.

If you have trouble with baking you may want to ask at [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com) which offers blender specific help.